# LaTeX Error: Option clash for package xcolor, even If I put listings before

Tags: tikz-pgf, color

```
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage{array}
    \usepackage{booktabs}
    \usepackage[draft]{pgf}
    \usepackage{listings}
    \usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
```

I want to use a color called 'Bittersweet' but I get this error

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Package `listings`  does not load `xcolor`, but package `pgf` does. In LaTeX you can load a package many times, but the option list of each package loading must be a subset of the options given at the first loading (exception is package `fontenc`).

### All options at first package loading

The problem is solved, if the first package loading contains all options:

```
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[draft]{pgf}
\usepackage{listings}
```

### `\PassOptionsToPackage`

However somtimes packages might be loaded in the document class already, or there are constraints in the package order that prevents the reordering of
the packages. Then `\PassOptionsToPackage` helps. It can even be loaded
before `\documentclass`. It gives the specified options to the package without
loading the package:

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{usenames,dvipsnames}{xcolor}
...
\usepackage[draft]{pgf}
% pgf can now load the package xcolor and loads it with
% options "usenames,dvipsnames".
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}
% or \usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
```

### Global options

BTW, the help text of the error message (press `h` at the interactive prompt or check the `.log`  file) for the option clash shows the options that need to be specified at the first loading of the package.

> ```
> See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
> Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
>  ...                                              
>
> l.5 \begin
>           {document}
> The package xcolor has already been loaded with options:
>   []
> There has now been an attempt to load it with options
>   [usenames,dvipsnames]
> Adding the global options:
>   ,usenames,dvipsnames
> to your \documentclass declaration may fix this.
> Try typing  <return>  to proceed.
> ```

Adding the options to the global options can also be used, but it is not the
best strategy IMHO, because also other unrelated packages see that options.
Unknown global options are ignored by packages, but known are then executed with
unintended side effects.

Comment: With packages like `xcolor`, `hyperref` etc. that are often loaded by other packages and classes, I definitely vote for `\PassOptionsToPackage` before `\documentclass`, it saves lots of troubles.